# rails undefined local variable or method `page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a pager as below which returns the error "undefined local variable or method `page'for...:

```
    <nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li class="previous <%= page == 0 ? 'display' : 'hidden' %>">
            <%= link_to_if page > 0, "&larr; Previous".html.safe,
                users_path(keywords: keywords, page: page - 1) %>
        </li>
        <li class="next">
            <<%= link_to "Next &rarr;".html.safe,
                users_path(keywords: keywords, page: page + 1) %>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It is called using `<% render "pager", locals: { keywords: @keywords, page: @page } %>`

The associated controller is

```
PAGE_SIZE = 20

def index
    @page = (params[:page] || 0).to_i

    if params[:keywords].present?
        @keywords = params[:keywords]
        user_search_term = UserSearchTerm.new(@keywords)
        @users = User.where(
            user_search_term.where_clause,
            user_search_term.where_args).
            order(user_search_term.order).
            offset(PAGE_SIZE * @page).limit(PAGE_SIZE)
    else
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can try to use `<% render partial: "pager", locals: { keywords: @keywords, page: @page } %>`

Comment: added partial: no more error, but what is the difference? Thought it was the same.

Comment: Actually, it's not the same. You can view the source here: [render method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8cb8ce98d903929342e2ca3a54a07ab5196baf93/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb#L26). So in your case, if you don't use `partial`, you also don't need to use `locals`. Can I add this as accepted answer?

Comment: yes of course you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `<% render partial: "pager", locals: { keywords: @keywords, page: @page } %>`

If you don't use `partial`, you also don't need to use `locals`.